# Adding JSON stored in database to JSON string

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON stored in a database.  Please assume I have a good reason for doing so.  I then retrieved it from the DB and wish to include it in another JSON string.  The following treats the JSON from the DB as standard strings instead of JSON as I desire. Will I need to loop over `$json_from_db` and first convert the `cmd` values to arrays/objects, or is there a better way?

```
<?php
$json_from_db=array(
    array('id'=>1,'cmd'=>'{"a":{}}'),
    array('id'=>3,'cmd'=>'{"b":{"name":"x","value":"xxx"}}'),
    array('id'=>5,'cmd'=>'{"b":{"name":"y","value":"yyy"}}'),
    array('id'=>9,'cmd'=>'{"c":{"name":"z","extra":"hello","more"=>1}}'),
);



$arr=array('a'=>"hello",'json'=>array('a'=>"hello"),'json_from_db'=>$json_from_db);
$json=json_encode($arr);
echo($json."\n\n");
print_r(json_decode($json));
```

OUTPUT

```
{"a":"hello","json":{"a":"hello"},"json_from_db":[{"id":1,"cmd":"\"a\":{}"},{"id":3,"cmd":"\"b\":{\"name\":\"x\",\"value\":\"xxx\"}"},{"id":5,"cmd":"\"b\":{\"name\":\"y\",\"value\":\"yyy\"}"},{"id":9,"cmd":"\"c\":{\"name\":\"z\",\"extra\":\"hello\",\"more\"=>1}"}]}

stdClass Object
(
    [a] => hello
    [json] => stdClass Object
        (
            [a] => hello
        )

    [json_from_db] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [cmd] => "a":{}
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [cmd] => "b":{"name":"x","value":"xxx"}
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [cmd] => "b":{"name":"y","value":"yyy"}
                )

            [3] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 9
                    [cmd] => "c":{"name":"z","extra":"hello","more"=>1}
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `Please assume I have a good reason for doing so` you know you doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `"b":{"name":"x","value":"xxx"}` isn't valid json.

You need to decode all cmd's json-string from `$json_from_db`,

```
array_walk_recursive($json_from_db, function (&$item, $key) {
    if ($key === 'cmd') {
        $item = json_decode($item, true);
    }
});
```

Then you can do

```
$arr = array(
    'a' => "hello",
    'json' => array('a'=>"hello"),
    'json_from_db' => $json_from_db
);

$json = json_encode($arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ReDLA).

Comment: Thanks Federico,  Yea, I just realized my JSON was messed up.  Let me check out your code. Thanks!

Comment: Nice use of `array_walk_recursive`.